# How do I get only the first column of this scatter matrix plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image]

I have this scatter matrix plot made using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix 

# selecting three numerical features 
features = ['TARGET_deathRate','incidenceRate', 'PctPublicCoverageAlone', 
        'povertyPercent', 'PctHS25_Over', 'PctPublicCoverage'] 

# plotting the scatter matrix 
# with the features 
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = '5'
scatter_matrix(df_add[features]) 
#plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.show()
```

I want to make a plot of only the first column from this plot, and getting rid of the other 5 columns. How would I do this?

Comment: Why not write a loop to only produce those scatter plots?

Comment: This function creates a matrix. You can refactor the source code to do what you want. If you don't want to write your own function and just want to use a function off the shelf, then you can try `seaborn.pairplot`.

Answer (score 1):

This task is pretty easy with [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) and [`pairplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html):

```
#! pip install seaborn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
sns.pairplot(penguins)
plt.show()
```

Default output:

[image]

Now suppose, you want the first column (`bill_length_mm` or `TARGET_deathRate` in your case):

```
sns.pairplot(data=penguins, x_vars='bill_length_mm')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]